# Reading last N columns of a CSV as a list with Pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

Imagine you have a log file which indicates some info separated by space, and from the third field until the last one, given information is a list of identifiers. For example, representing the id number of the F1 cars ending each race (header is given to explain the example):

```
Number_of_race Whatever_data From_here_list_of__car_ids
1 211 2 3 5 7 8 11 18
```

(meaning that cars 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 11 and 18 ended the race number 1 for whatever data 211)

I can know the minimum number of columns for any row (2) and I can also know the maximum (If last car is #18, therefore 20 is maximum).

I could set column names when reading the file as a CSV, so the last 18 columns would have some null values, and then somehow combine the 18 columns as a list of the non-null values. But I suppose there is a simpler way of doing this with Pandas.

Any suggestion?

Comment: what did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can read the file as a single column then split them after  :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('race.csv',names=['FULL'],header=0)
df['Number_of_race'] =df.FULL.str.split(' ').str[0]
df['Whatever_data'] =df.FULL.str.split(' ').str[1] 
df['From_here_list_of__car_ids'] =df.FULL.str.split(' ').str[2:]
```